# How do i call server.stop?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

In the MainAvtivity.java i added this two methods:

```
@Override
    protected void onStart()
    {
        super.onStart();
        TextToSpeechServer.main(null);
    }
```

And

```
@Override
protected void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
}
```

and this is the TextToSpeechServer code:

```
package com.adi.webservertest;

import java.util.Map;

/**
 * An example of subclassing NanoHTTPD to make a custom HTTP server.
 */
public class TextToSpeechServer extends NanoHTTPD {
    public TextToSpeechServer() {
        super(8080);
    }

    @Override public Response serve(IHTTPSession session) {
        Method method = session.getMethod();
        String uri = session.getUri();
        System.out.println(method + " '" + uri + "' ");

        String msg = "<html><body><h1>Hello server</h1>\n";
        Map<String, String> parms = session.getParms();

        if (parms.get("say") != null)
            msg += "<p>Hello, " + parms.get("say") + "!</p>"; 

        if (parms.get("username") == null)
            msg +=
                    "<form action='?' method='get'>\n" +
                            "  <p>Your name: <input type='text' name='username'></p>\n" +
                            "</form>\n";
        else
            msg += "<p>Hello, " + parms.get("username") + "!</p>";

        msg += "</body></html>\n";

        return new Response(msg);
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ServerRunner.run(TextToSpeechServer.class);
    }
}
```

The method in the MainActivity.java onStart is working fine.
But what should i call and how in the onStop method to stop the server ?